# Filter PIVOT information

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a query that utilizes the PIVOT function. Is there any function that could be used to filter or simplify the pivoted result? i.e. WHERE, HAVING, QUALIFY

Query:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyPec.png

PS: z.door_id have been edited to door_id

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: PIVOT is part of FROM, thus WHERE, etc. can be applied

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Based on my query, I can add another WHERE after my PIVOT? May I know what is the sequence for the functions? FROM>WHERE>SELECT>PIVOT?